# How can I write a where clause to get dates between some date in the last month and some date in the current month, dynamically?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to write a query where I need all the records between the 26th of last month and the 25th of the current month and if the current date is between 26 and 31 then I need records between 26 and 31 of just this month.

The monthly cycle is from 26 to 25 and the query is supposed to be executed every day. I'm not able to figure out how to write a where clause for this.

this is the structure of the table that I have:

```
order_id    order_date    bill
  1          2021-02-25    500
  2          2021-02-25    1000
  3          2021-02-26    1500
  4          2021-02-27    150
  5          2021-02-28    25
  6          2021-03-02    78
              .
              .
              .
 4250        2021-03-25    500
```

Comment: You need a WHERE clause with 2 OR statements. The first one should fetch all records where current date is less than 26 and order_date is between 26th of last month and 25th of current month. The second statement should fetch all records where current date is between 26 and 31 and the order_date is between 26th and 31st of current month.

Comment: Today's the 27th. What would the desired result look like. Last week was the 20th. What would the result have looked like then?

Answer (score 0):

The general format of the query might look like this:

```
select *
from t
where
day(curdate()) between 26 and 31) and order_date between a and b or
day(curdate()) not between 26 and 31) and order_date between c and d
```

or:

```
select *
from t
where
order_date between if(curdate()) between 26 and 31, a, c) and if(curdate() between 26 and 31, b, d)
```

where a, b and c would use date calculations.  For a it would be `adddate(subdate(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) day), interval 26 day)`.  b would be `last_day(curdate())`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a WHERE clause using the BETWEEN predicate, there is a way to use `EXISTS (subquery)`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable m
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 DAY) d) t
 WHERE m.order_date
    BETWEEN
        d + INTERVAL (-DAY(d)+1+25) DAY
        AND
        d + INTERVAL 25 DAY)
```

The extraction range is the period obtained by adding 25 to the 1st day and the last day of the month including the start date.

`LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 DAY)` always maps to the last day of the same month.

```
2021-02-26 -> 2021-02-01 -> 2021-02-28
2021-02-27 -> 2021-02-02 -> 2021-02-28
2021-02-28 -> 2021-02-03 -> 2021-02-28
2021-03-01 -> 2021-02-04 -> 2021-02-28
:
2021-03-25 -> 2021-02-28 -> 2021-02-28
```

About `d + INTERVAL (-DAY(d)+1+25) DAY`, `-DAY(d)+1` is the first day, so `-DAY(d)+1+25` is 26th of that month.
`d + INTERVAL 25 DAY` is 25th of that next month.

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jp6jFSSQSXUf9s5ac6Fmkk/1)

Comment: No results for the query @etsuhisa

Comment: Sorry, I mistake. The correct query is `LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 DAY)`. I also fixed the link to Fiddle.